# Sleep wake failure (Catalina, MBP 16" 2019)

Tags: catalina, kernel-panic

I've been having a recurring issue where my MacBook Pro crashes while sleeping. Any indication if this is a hardware issue or something in software?

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8002616487): "AppleIntelFramebuffer::setPowerState(0xffffff834a90d000 : 0xffffff7f85ba8d88, 1 -> 0) timed out after 45939 ms"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.101.6/iokit/Kernel/IOServicePM.cpp:5296
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa3e8a13b40 : 0xffffff8001f215cd 
0xffffffa3e8a13b90 : 0xffffff800205a3c5 
0xffffffa3e8a13bd0 : 0xffffff800204bf7e 
0xffffffa3e8a13c20 : 0xffffff8001ec7a40 
0xffffffa3e8a13c40 : 0xffffff8001f20c97 
0xffffffa3e8a13d40 : 0xffffff8001f21087 
0xffffffa3e8a13d90 : 0xffffff80026c2c7c 
0xffffffa3e8a13e00 : 0xffffff8002616487 
0xffffffa3e8a13e50 : 0xffffff8002615d69 
0xffffffa3e8a13e60 : 0xffffff800262d2fe 
0xffffffa3e8a13ea0 : 0xffffff8002614b18 
0xffffffa3e8a13ec0 : 0xffffff8001f63545 
0xffffffa3e8a13f40 : 0xffffff8001f63071 
0xffffffa3e8a13fa0 : 0xffffff8001ec713e 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19E287

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: AB0AA7EE-3D03-3C21-91AD-5719D79D7AF6
Kernel slide:     0x0000000001c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8001e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8001d00000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 34317245501611
last loaded kext at 32801181302746: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f85c44000, size 45056)
last unloaded kext at 33137231350415: >!UAudio  322.2 (addr 0xffffff7f8922d000, size 434176)
loaded kexts:
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    3.0.8
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.1.16
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.1.16
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.4f6
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.5
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>AGDCBacklightControl   5.1.16
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.3
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.426
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.5
>!AMuxControl2  5.1.16
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.3
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.11
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.101.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  3.0.8
|IOAVB!F    840.3
>!ASSE  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 3.0.8
@!AGPUWrangler  5.1.16
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.4f6
|IONDRVSupport  575.1
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.8
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.4.5
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.1.16
>!AGraphicsControl  5.1.16
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.4f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.4f6
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   575.1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.101.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.101.1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.4f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.4f6
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.101.3
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.101.1
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Answer (score -2):

I bought a MacBook Pro 13" 2019 last year and experienced the same problem. After a while, the Kernel Panics stopped happening. I remember that I updated my MacBook to Catalina and then, the Kernal Panics never happened again. So maybe you should update your MacBook to the newest macOS Catalina Version available (macOS 10.15.5).